# Different result executing the same function [C++]

Tags: c++, function, class

Hello and thanks in advance.
I need to create a Tetris project in C++, i have the boards and pieces classes but i want to do an initializer class, so what im doing is this

```
#include "Initializer.h"

void Initializer::drawBoard()
{

}

// --------------------------------- Public Part ----------------------- //

Initializer::Initializer(Board *bBoard, Pieces *pPieces)
{

}

void Initializer::drawScene()
{
    bBoard->showBoard();
}
```

Here is the board class:

```
Board::Board(Pieces *mPieces)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
      for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
      {
        mBoard[x][y] = 0;
      }
    }
}

void Board::showBoard()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
          if(mBoard[x][y] == 0)
          {
            cout << 0;
          }
          else
          {
            cout << "x";
          }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

and the main function

```
#include "Pieces.h"
#include "Board.h"
#include "Initializer.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main(int numeroArgumentos, char *argumentos[])
{
  srand (time(NULL));
  int randomNumber = rand() % 6;
  Pieces mPieces;
  Board bBoard(&mPieces);
  Initializer iIOS(&bBoard, &mPieces);
  bBoard.showBoard();
  iIOS.drawScene();
  return 0;
}
```

the problem is, i get two different results when i execute the main function as you can see in the image (bBoard.showBoard is the left result, and the other one is the iIOS.drawScene())
[image]

What i have to do to get the correct board with the two functions?

Comment: Removed the C tag for you, since this is clearly not C.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Your `Initializer` constructor doesn't do anything with its arguments.

Comment: Use the debugger to take a look at `bBoard` in `drawScene`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're getting is undefined behavior. Your constructor for `Initializer` isn't actually capturing the values in `board`, so it's presumably just running through memory that doesn't belong to it.

Answer (score 1):

The `Initializer` constructor needs to save its parameters in the appropriate member variables. Just naming the parameters the same as the member variables doesn't do this automatically. You can use a member initializer list to do this.

```
Initializer::Initializer(Board *bBoard, Pieces *pPieces): bBoard(bBoard), pPieces(pPieces) {}
```